# How to solve it using Method $2,3?$

Tags: contest-math, conic-sections

> If the equation of tangent at point $P(3,4)$ on the parabola whose axis is x-axis is $3x-4y+7=0 $ then find the distance of the tangent from the focus of the parabola.

**Method $1$:**

I let the equation of parabola to be $y^2=4a(x-h)$

Putting $(3,4),$ I get one relation in $a,h$.

I wrote the tangent equation as $y=m(x-h)+a/m$. Putting $m=3/4$ and comparing with the given equation, I get another relation in $a,h$.

Solving simultaneously, I get $h=1/3,a=3/2$, thus focus is $(11/6,0)$

Therefore, the perpendicular distance from tangent is $5/2$.

**Method $2$:**

On [doubtnut](https://www.doubtnut.com/question-answer/if-the-equation-of-the-tangent-at-the-point-p34-on-the-parabola-whose-axis-is-the-x-axis-is-3x-4y-7--278660227), they have a video solution.

They seem to be saying the slope of focal chord is $\tan2\theta$ if the slope of tangent is $\tan\theta$. Is this true?

**Method $3$**

Can we use the fact that the foot of perpendicular from focus on any tangent lies on the tangent at vertex?

Comment: your answer is correct, using Method 1. Use Method 2 and 3 to find the answer and then try to prove Methods 2 and 3

Comment: @Lozenges the answer is coming correct through Method 2 as well. But I don't know why this method works. As to, why would the slope of focal chord be $\tan2\theta$ if the slope of tangent is $\tan\theta?$. I tried Method 3. But not able to conclude.

Comment: Method 2: $\tan \theta = m =3/4$. Use a trig identity to show  $\tan 2 \theta$ equals the slope of $FP$, where $F$ is the focus

Comment: @Lozenges but we don't know the coordinates of focus unless we use Method 1.

Comment: Method 2: we know $\tan \theta$ therefore we can find $\tan 2\theta$ which gives the slope of $FP$. Given $P$, we can find $F$ on the $x$-axis

Comment: @Lozenges thanks for the replies but my question is exactly why $\tan2\theta$ would be the slope of focal chord. Is this a general property?

Comment: Or maybe I am trying to ask why the slope of FP is $\tan2\theta?$ Or maybe I am asking why FP would make angle $2\theta$ with x-axis?

Comment: If T is where the tangent ciluts x-axis then will FT be equal to FP? Why?

Comment: Method 2 follows from the reflective property: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#Proof_of_the_reflective_property

Comment: HINT. If $H$ is the projection of $P$ on the directrix, then the focus is the reflection of $H$ about the tangent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T$ is where the tangent cuts the $x$-axis then will $FT$ equal $FP$?
Yes.

Consider the points on the $x$-axis along with their $x$-coordinates
$$T(t), D(h-a),V(h),F(h+a),K(r)$$  $D$ is the point where the directrix cuts the $x$-axis, $V$ and $F$ are the vertex and the focus respectively and $P(r,s)$ is the point on the parabola, therefore $FP=DK$.
With this notation, the equation of the parabola becomes $y^2=4a(x-h)$ and we have $$s^2=4a(r-h)$$

The slope of the tangent line can be written in two ways, rise over run and also using the derivative

$$\frac {s}{r-t}=\frac {2a}{s}$$

Eliminate $s$ and $a$ from these equations to get

$$h=\frac{r+t}{2}$$

This shows that $V$ is the midpoint of $TK$ implying $FT=DK=FP$

Comment: Hey, I can see that FP=DK. And, V is the mid point of TK. From this, how do we conclude that FT=DK?

Comment: $V$ is also the midpoint of $DF$. So $FT=FV+VT=DV+VK=DK$

Comment: Thankyou, got it!

Answer (score 3):

Let $H$ be the projection of $P$ on the directrix: focus $S$ is the reflection of $H$ about the tangent. The midpoint $M$ of $HS$ has $y=2$ and lies on the tangent, hence $M=(1/3,2)$.

Let $V$ be the projection of $M$ on the $x$-axis and $K$ the projection of $M$ on $PH$.
Distance $SM$ can be found from the similarity of $MVS$ and $PKM$:
$$
MS:PM=MV:PK,
$$
where $PK=8/3$, $MK=MV=2$, $PM=10/3$.
Hence:
$$
MS={5\over2}.
$$

[image]

Comment: Thanks, very clever approach!